# Should we have a meta meta math Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

The problem is that this question needs to be discussed, but it can't be discussed here, so it must be discussed in meta meta math SE. But discussing it there would mean we already have a meta$^2$ MSE, so the question would actually be "should we have a $m^3$ MSE?" But we could only discuss that on $m^4$ MSE or higher, and so on.

So my thought is that we should have a $m^2$ MSE, but only if we allow $m^3, m^4, \dots$ MSE's as well.

One reason for having a $m^2$ MSE is because I was about to ask why each question must include one of "bug-feature, request, discussion, support" when I realized that this should go on the non-existent $m^2$ MSE.

Comment: This sounds to me to be a fine question for meta. I can't think of something that merits a metameta. I will add that the closest thing to a proper metameta is [meta.stackexchange](meta.stackexchange.com), although this is perhaps better thought of as the abstract meta for generic stackexchange sites.

Comment: Is this a joke or a sincere question?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Sincere. I added an example of a question that would go on $m^2 $ MSE

Comment: I think that some time ago we decided meta was idempotent.

Comment: I will add that some basic information about required tags can be found [in the Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) and on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/required-tags).

Comment: If, in fact, your question is sincere, perhaps the better question would have been to ask if it is possible to edit the current description of meta.math.se to welcome not only questions about math.se,, but also questions about meta.math.se.  That would be the most reasonable thing to ask, if you are "sincerely" interested in having a place to go on which you can ask questions about meta.math.se, itself.  Your reasoning in your post already expresses the absurdity of having a meta.meta.math.se, which would necessitate a meta.meta.meta.math.se, ad infinitum.

Answer (score 10):

In order to avoid creating countably infinite meta sites, I think it would be best to allow such questions here.

Comment: What about an uncountably infinite number? :p

Comment: Let's have $\text{Meta}^\omega\text{MSE}$

Answer (score -2):

No, because as every group element has an inverse element, we would need a:

> $\text{meta}^{-1}$Mathematics site

Comment: Well, what about $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?